# How does code run in a WebService?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm currently working on a WebService that is meant to become used by numerous different thin clients. I have been testing it so far with 1 website as the client.

My question is, the web service has classes right. When someone logs onto a website that uses the webservice, is the main class instantiated for that instance of someone using it?

For example during debugging I have 1 client.

1. The service starts off with a variable that is instaniated as "Hello World" The client asks for the string from the service, then sends it back.
2. The service then changes an internal
   variable to be equal to the one sent
   by the client. The service then
   append 2 to the end, so the variable
   is now "Hello World 2".
3. The client asks for the updated
   string, and gets Hello World 2.
4. Another user logs on. They ask for
   the string, expecting Hello World
   but get Hello World 2. Now when the
   send it back they get Hello World 2

   1. This is an undesirable result, and is what I'm trying to avoid.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You should not be using ASMX web services unless you have no choice at all. All new development should use WCF.

Comment: How hard is the switch? Can I still use SOAP clients in my thin-clients?

Comment: The switch is not hard. WCF is SOAP plus a lot more - about 100 x as functional as ASMX services. Besides, Microsoft now considers ASMX to be a "legacy technology".

Comment: @John Saunders: or just use MVC or IHttpHandlers to serve structured data, don't even need a service stack for lots of tasks these days.

Comment: @Wyatt: that depends on your requirements. It's always been possible to use HttpHandlers, and yet there are often good reasons not to do so - reasons like, "don't reinvent the wheel".

Comment: @John: conversely, is there always a need to swat flies with flamethrowers? When there is more configuration than code you could have problems . . .

Comment: @Wyatt: this is a discussion for a different forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WebService in ASP.NET works much like a customer service call center. A "pool" of HttpApplications, each representing a connection to your webserver via a browser or other program, are maintained by the ASP.NET server, either actively handling a service call or waiting to receive one. When a service call comes in, it is routed to an idle instance from the pool, which runs the specified method and returns the result which is transmitted as a SOAP response (or using whatever protocol you've set up for your service). The service class then returns to its idle state. Your next call may be handled by a different instance of the service class ("your call is being transferred to the next available representative") than the one that handled your last call.

For almost any circumstance, this architecture is just fine. Service class instances can, as part of their running, read from and write to centralized data stores to which all other instances have access, so as long as either (a.) a service method doesn't need any specialized information to produce the correct answer, or (b.) the service can get any specialized information from this central data store, it doesn't matter which instance handles each call.

However, services also support session state. A client may be directed to a service, give it some information to remember without writing it anywhere centrally, and then have to call back to that same service instance to give it more information before a determinate result can be arrived at. To do this, the client requests a session identifier from the service; basically like asking a CSR in a call center for their direct extension. Some work is done while connected, then each side may go off and do other work without being connected, then the client will call back, provide the session identifier it was given, and its next service call will be handled by the instance that handled the last request. While a session identifier is outstanding, the service will remain idle in the pool, "remembering" any information it has been given, until either the client with that session identifier says it's done (closing the session), or the client hasn't called back in a given time (timing out).

Comment: Okay, I'm all converted to WCF, but not I'm having this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035981/wcf-configuring-server-to-remember-data

Answer (score 5):

If you want state to be reset for new clients, then you need to keep track of which clients have connected and serve them data appropriately. This might entail requiring a call to setup a session, so that you can assign and return a token to the client, which is then utilized for all subsequent calls.

An alternative is to write your service using WCF, and then use the `PerSession` `InstanceContextMode`, which will construct a new service object for every session. In this case, you still need to indicate which calls begin a session and which calls end a session. For more, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx).

Comment: I've looked into the WCF solution, but I'm having trouble letting the service know when to end a session. The user never really ends the session since my webpage has some forms and button that the user can click and it's supposed to retrieve the data from the server. is there some way I can dispose of the data only when the user actually leaves the webpage?